# Equality for the Supremum of the mean square error

Tags: probability, mean-square-error

Given a statistical model $(X,\mathcal{F},(\mathbb{P}_\vartheta)_{\vartheta\in\Theta}$) and $\hat{\vartheta}$ be an estimator. Then (here the MSE of $\hat{\vartheta}$ in terms of $\vartheta$ is denoted as $R(\hat{\vartheta},\vartheta)$.

$$
\sup_{\vartheta\in \Theta}R(\hat{\vartheta},\vartheta)= \sup_\Pi \int_\Theta R(\hat{\vartheta},\vartheta)\Pi (d\vartheta)
$$
Where the supremum is taken over all a-priori distributions $\Pi$. Now what is clear to me ist that
$$
R(\hat{\vartheta},\vartheta)\leq \sup_\Pi \int_\Theta R(\hat{\vartheta},\vartheta)\Pi (d\vartheta)
$$
This can be shown using the Dirac-measure as one of the a-priori measures in $\Pi$. What is not clear to me is the other way, where the proof only says
$$
\text{It is clear that } \sup_{\vartheta\in \Theta}R(\hat{\vartheta},\vartheta)\geq \int_\Theta R(\hat{\vartheta},\vartheta)\Pi (d\vartheta)
$$
How can this be shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think applying [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Lebesgue_measure) proves the claim. ($p=\infty$ corresponds to supremum, and $q=1$ results in 1 integrating over the prior.) But I cannot see how "it is clear" either!

**EDIT**

On a second thought, it is clear. Suppose $f(x) < M$. Then $\int f(x)g(x)dx <  M \int g(x)dx $. Here, $M$ is the supremum of MSE, and $ \int \Pi(d\vartheta) = 1 $.